# How do I read a Maps values to my serializer?

Tags: java, serialization, redis, guice, kryo

I would like to read the values that are stored in my Redis database (by another program) into my Kryo serializer. Right now when I perform a cluster.hgetall I get all the values I have stored in the database as a Map. I'd like to be able to turn this map into an Object using Kryo but I can't pass a key value map to it, since it'd like a data array or a stream to be able to turn into a Kryo Input object. How do I get from Map to a new Input() that I can deserialize to a new Object?

```
// here hgetall returns a Map<String, String>
// I'd really like to be able to do something like this
// but it won't work since I don't know how to turn Map<String, String> into a kryo Input object

kryoSerializer.deserialize(redis.hgetall())

KryoSerializer(){
    public Object deserialize(Map<String, String> redisReturnMap, Class clazz){
    //  turn redisReturnMap magically into clazz object 
    }
}

// Example of an object stored in the map
class Foo(){
    private string Id;
    private string someInfo;
    private Bar Some subClass;

    //  setters and getters
}
```

To clarify I'm completely ok with a very hacky way to solve this problem. I'd prefer an elegant solution, but even a rudimentary fix (like somehow concatenating the keys and values together into a large string and deserializing form there) would be a great place to start for me. I can't seem to figure this out on my own.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157236/kryo-serialization-with-nested-hashmap-with-custom-class

Comment: Thank you for linking this. But to my understanding it's about serializing an Actual HashMap object. Not an object that is Mapped into a Map. Or if not, I'd need some help understanding how to implement the solution.